# Turn a div with a google map into a link - w3c validate

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, w3c-validation

I have a small google map on a page.  Currently, I have a link tag around the div to make it link to a different page with a larger google map.

This all works perfectly, but it's not w3c validating.

My code before that works, but isn't valid:

```
    <a href="http://www.mysite.com">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:298px;height:150px;"></div>
    </a>
```

This is after, which is valid, but doesn't work!:

```
<div onClick="location.http://www.mysite.com';" style="cursor:pointer;">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:298px;height:150px;"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that on the second version, when I click, nothing happens.  If I double click, it zooms in on the map.  I just want it to be a link no matter what you do.

Thanks.

Comment: What were the validation errors?

Comment: I get an error basically saying you can't have a div inside of an <a href>

Comment: should be `onclick="location.href='http://www.mysite.com';"`

Comment: Onclick doesn't seem to do the trick, no matter what I do.  Maybe because this is a google map container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the DOCTYPE you've used for validation.

I guess you validate a DOCTYPE that doesn't allow block-elements(div) inside inline-elements(a) .

Solution: use a inline-element(e.g. span) instead of the div and set the `display` to `block`:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.com">
  <span id="map_canvas" style="display:block;width:298px;height:150px;"></span>
</a>
```

- [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/8k9ZJ/)
- [**Validation(XHTML 1.0 Strict)**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net%2Fdoktormolle%2F8k9ZJ%2Fshow%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.3)

Comment: This didn't work.  The div is a google map and doesn't seem to display when used in a span.

Comment: Then you made a mistake, it doesn't matter if the element is a div or a span

Answer (score 0):

```
 <a href="http://www.mysite.com">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="width:298px;height:150px;"></div>
    </a>
```

Now its valid. :) You missed a "

Comment: I updated my post, actually that  quote isn't missing in my source code, I just took it off by accident when changing the url for this post. Sorry.